# Python How to print dictionary in one line?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, printing

Hi I am new to Python and I am struggling regarding how to print dictionary.

I have a dictionary as shown below.

```
dictionary = {a:1,b:1,c:2}
```

How can I print dictionary in one line as shown below?

```
a1b1c2
```

I want to print keys and values in one line but could not figure out by myself.

I would appreciate your advice!

Comment: `d = {'a':1,'b':1,'c':2}; "".join([k+str(v) for k,v in d.items()])` ?

Comment: Please show your code attempt at this and explain what difficulty you are having

Comment: a, b and c are variables?

Comment: @idjaw I tried like this. for k, v in count.items():  print("{0}{1}".format(k, v)). But this code print values in multiple lines.

Comment: @alvas  Thank you so much! your solution worked very well!

Comment: To fix your own code, you have to pass `end=''` in your print method. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

Answer (score 16):

With a dictionary, e.g.

```
dictionary = {'a':1,'b':1,'c':2}
```

You could try:

```
print ''.join(['{0}{1}'.format(k, v) for k,v in dictionary.iteritems()])
```

Resulting in

> a1c2b1

If order matters, try using an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), as described by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key) post.

Comment: ```def format_dict(dictionary): 
    return ' '.join(['{0}={1}'.format(k, v) for k,v in dictionary.iteritems()])```

Answer (score 6):

If you want a string to contain the answer, you could do this:

```
>>> dictionary = {'a':1,'b':1,'c':2}
>>> result = "".join(str(key) + str(value) for key, value in dictionary.items())
>>> print(result)
c2b1a1
```

This uses the join method on an empty string. Dict's are not ordered, so the order of the output may vary.

*Update* - Using f-strings you could do this too:

```
>>> result = "".join(f"{key}{value}" for key, value in dictionary.items())
```

Comment: Note that in Python 3.6 dicts are now ordered (unless you mess with them a lot), so the order of the output in 3.6+ will be deterministic.